# Quicksort with dynamically linked list

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Hay i am trying to make a quicksort method for a dynamically linked list class i made. But i keep getting a NullPointerException and cant work out why.

```
 private void addToEnd(IntList y){
if(y.head != null ){
        IntNode tmp = this.head;
    while(tmp.getNext() != null){     //line 68
    tmp = tmp.getNext();

}
tmp.setNext(y.head);
}
  }


 public IntList Quicksort(){
if(this.length() > 1){
    IntList bList = new IntList();
    IntList sList = new IntList();
    IntList pivot = new IntList();

    pivot.addNode(head);
    int pivotInt = this.head.getValue();
    IntNode test = this.head.getNext();

    while(test != null){

        if(test.getValue() > pivotInt){

            bList.addNode(test);

        }else{ sList.addNode(test);}

    test = test.getNext();
}

    sList.Quicksort().addToEnd(pivot);
    sList.addToEnd(bList.Quicksort());


}
return this;
}
```

I am getting the NullPointerException at line 68 and have no idea why. Can anyone help me out here? Line 68 is

```
while(tmp.getNext() != null){     //line 68
```

Comment: Why? Quicksort is designed for arrays.

Comment: -1, please post a stack trace and the line the error is at. We aren't going to count 68 lines to help a stranger for free.

Comment: I know but its what i have been asked for so who am i to disagree :)

Answer (score 1):

> I am getting the NullPointerException at line 68 and have no idea why.

The "why" is that `tmp` is null:

```
IntNode tmp = this.head;
while(tmp.getNext() != null){     //line 68
```

In other words `this` is an `IntList` (I guess) that has `null` in its `head` field.

But whether that is a "valid" state, and (if not) how it got into that state is anyone's guess.  If this is a valid state, then the fix is to rewrite `addToEnd` to deal with the case of adding to an empty list properly; i.e. `this.head` being null.  (It is not as quite simple as the comment below suggests ... but this is an obviously a learning exercise, so you can work it out for yourself.)

---

(FWIW, sorting a linked list in place is never going to be easy or efficient.  The simple way to do it is to copy the list elements into an array, sort the array, and then repopulate the list.)

Comment: `while(tmp != null){` would really solve this problem.

Comment: That's assuming that it is valid to have an IntList with a `null` head.  I'm not prepared to make that call ... without seeing the rest of the code.